# Bash unable to create directory

Tags: bash, docker, hdfs, mkdir

In docker, I want to copy a file **README.md** from an existing directory ***/opt/ibm/labfiles*** to a new one ***/input/tmp***. I try this

```
hdfs dfs -put /opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md input/tmp
```

to no effect, because there seems to be no /input folder in the root. So I try to create it:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /input
mkdir:'/input': File exists
```

However, when I ls, there is no input file[image] or directory
[image]

How can I create a folder and copy the file? Thank you!!

Comment: You are confused with what is HDFS and local filesystem

Comment: And you aren't using Spark shell anywhere in the question, so I've editted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `hdfs dfs -ls /` if you want to see there is an input folder that exists in HDFS at the root.

You cannot `cd` into an HDFS directory

It's also worth mentioning that the leading slash is important. In other words,

This will try to put the file in HDFS at  `/user/<name>/input/tmp`

```
hdfs dfs -put /opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md input/tmp
```

While this puts the file at the root of HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -put /opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md /input/tmp
```

Comment: Thank you, with your help I can see that I created the folders correctly. However, I could not copy the README.md file there.

Comment: Well, without the leading slash to the input directory, you have to create the user folder as well. Typically, I just throw files into `/tmp` when testing stuff. Less characters to type and it's guaranteed to be there