# Bash - how to check if file has been uploaded to hdfs?

Tags: bash, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I [created a folder in hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589904/bash-unable-to-create-directory). Now, I tried to upload a file from my local filesystem to the tmp folder, like so:

```
hdfs dfs -put opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md /user/root/input/tmp
```

But I get the message:

```
put: '/user/root/input/tmp': File exists
```

What I don't understand: When I run the test if the file is there, I don't see the file listed, but the folder has the size of the file (4811 bites). Yet again, tmp might not even be a folder:
[image]

- How could I see if tmp is a folder?
- How could I see if the README.md file IS in tmp, or if not, how could I put it there?
- When starting SparkShell from here, I cannot access the file (Input path does not exist). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that `tmp` is a file. If it was a directory it would show `drw_r__r__` notice the `d`, yours doesnt have that, so its a file.

You should have run:

`hdfs dfs -put opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md /user/root/input/tmp/README.md`

Comment: Why should one use `hadoop fs` instead of `hdfs dfs`?

Comment: @daemon12 Thanks for asking, i just checked and its actually `hadoop dfs` that was deprecated.  I'll remove that part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case if tmp is a cataloge which already exist, you could write directly to it omitting the filename:

```
hdfs dfs -put opt/ibm/labfiles/README.md /user/root/input/tmp/
```

Add extra **'/'** at the end. If at the end you set **'/'** - it will write into catalog, otherwise command will try to create a file with the name after last **'/'** symbol in path